# How to use scrapy to get to the next chapter on fanfiction.net?

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy

On fanfiction.net, this is the HTML code to get the chapters of a story:

```html
<select id="chap_select" title="Chapter Navigation" name="chapter" onchange="self.location = '/s/13109220/'+ this.options[this.selectedIndex].value + '/Son-of-the-Hunt';">
  <option value="1" selected="">1. Chapter 1</option>
  <option value="2">2. Camp</option>
  <option value="3">3. Chapter 3</option>
</select>
```

What I want is to use this to go to the next chapter and keep downloading the text content, but the normal way of doing it with it calling `self.fanfiction()` recursively which would not work because of the `self.storyNum += 1` line.

```py
import scrapy, docx, time
import subprocess as sp

class FanfictionDownloader(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "fanfiction"
    storyNum = 0
    nextPage = False
    urls = []
    docText = ''
    title = ''

    def start_requests(self):
        sp.call('cls', shell=True)
        self.urls = list(str(input("Enter url seperated by a comma and space (, ): ")).split(', '))
        for url in self.urls:
            if self.urls[self.storyNum].startswith('https://www.fanfiction.net/s/'):
                yield scrapy.Request(url=url, callback=self.fanfiction)
            elif self.urls[self.storyNum].startswith('https://www.wattpad.com/'):
                yield scrapy.Request(url=url, callback=self.wattpad)
            else:
                print('Not a valid link, ending downloader.')
                time.sleep(5)
                quit()
                sp.call('cls', shell=True)

    def fanfiction(self, response):
        self.storyNum += 1
        doc = docx.Document()
        chapters = ''
        totalChapters = 0
        currentChapter = 1
        i = 0
        for para in response.css('div#storytext > p'):
            text = (para.xpath('text() | */text() | */*/text()').getall())
            self.title = (response.xpath('//*[@id="profile_top"]/b/text()').get())
            storyId = ((response.xpath('//*[@id="profile_top"]/span[4]/text()[5]').get()).replace(' - id: ', ''))
            chapters = (response.xpath('//*[@id="chap_select"]/option/text()').getall())
            totalChapters = len(chapters[0:int(len(chapters) / 2)])
            finalText = [
                [x.replace('\u00ef', 'ï').replace('\u2013', '–').replace('\u2026', '...') for x in text],
                ['Story %s: %s' % (self.storyNum,  self.urls[self.storyNum - 1])],
                ['Title: %s' % (self.title)],
                ['Story ID: %s' % (storyId)],
                ['Total Chapters: %s' % (totalChapters)],
                ['Chapter Names: %s' % [chapters[0:int(len(chapters) / 2)]]],
            ]
            if len(finalText[0][0]) > 1:
                self.docText = (''.join(finalText[0][0:]))
            else:
                self.docText = finalText[0][0]
            if self.nextPage == False:
                doc.add_paragraph(self.docText)
            else:
                doc.add_page_break(self.docText)
                self.nextPage = False
                doc.add_paragraph()
            sp.call('cls', shell=True)
            doc.save('./../%s.docx' % (self.title))
            i += 1
            yield {'line ' + str(i): finalText}
            sp.call('cls', shell=True)

    def wattpad(self, response):
        pass
```

Answer (score 1):

Do you really need to keep a counter for the story num?

I think you can just yield the next page as long as you find one, something like:

```
if response.xpath('//button[text()="Next >"]'):
    next_link = response.xpath('//button[text()="Next >"]')[0].attrib['onclick'].replace('self.location=', '').replace("'", '')
    yield response.follow('https://www.fanfiction.net' + next_link, self.fanfiction)
```

As mentioned in the comments, you should use an item pipeline to care about "storing" your items in your documents.

Here is something to give you an idea, which works for me, and that you have to adapt to your use case:

```
import docx
import scrapy

class StoryPipeline:

    def open_spider(self, spider):
        self.doc = docx.Document()

    def process_item(self, item, spider):
        if 'title' in item:
            self.title = item['title']
            self.doc.add_paragraph(str(item))
        else:
            self.doc.add_paragraph('\n\n'.join(item['paragraphs']))

    def close_spider(self, spider):
        self.doc.save('./%s.docx' % (self.title))


class FanfictionDownloader(scrapy.Spider):

    name = "fanfiction.net"

    custom_settings = {
        "ITEM_PIPELINES": {
            "myspider.StoryPipeline": 300,
        }
    }

    def start_requests(self):
        start_url = 'https://www.fanfiction.net/s/11734723/1/This-Past-Storm'
        yield scrapy.Request(url=start_url, callback=self.parse)

    def parse(self, response):

        title = response.xpath('//*[@id="profile_top"]/b/text()').get()
        storyId = response.xpath('//*[@id="profile_top"]/span[4]/text()[5]').get().replace(' - id: ', '')
        chapters = response.xpath('(//select[@id="chap_select"])[1]/option/text()').getall()

        yield {
            'title': title,
            'storyId': storyId,
            'chapters': chapters,
            'totalChapters': len(chapters),
        }

        for x in self._parse_paragraphs(response):
            yield x

    def parse_next(self, response):

        for x in self._parse_paragraphs(response):
            yield x

    def _parse_paragraphs(self, response):
        paragraphs = response.xpath('//div[@id="storytext"]//text()').getall()

        yield {'paragraphs': paragraphs}

        next_button = response.xpath('(//button[text()="Next >"])[1]/@onclick').get()
        if next_button:
            next_url = next_button.replace('self.location=', '').replace("'", '')
            yield scrapy.Request(url=response.urljoin(next_url), callback=self.parse_next)
```

Comment: if i do this, the file is overwritten.

Comment: Yes, because you are mixing concerns in your spider. Your spider should be concerned about the navigation and fetching items from the page. The persistence of your items in the documents should ideally be done in an item pipeline: https://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/item-pipeline.html   - In the item pipeline, you can open the document in open_spider(), use process_item() to add elements, and close the document in close_spider()

Comment: could you post an example, or how it would be done? I a newbie to scrapy